# If s1=√2 and let s_n=√2•√s_n for n>=2 then s_n converges to 2

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, upper-lower-bounds

Let $s_1=\sqrt{2}$ and let $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s_n}$ for $n \ge 2.$
Then to prove:
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\{s_n\}=2$$

My attempt: it is found by induction that $s_n\le 2$ for $n \ge 2.$

And $$s_n = 2^{1/2 + 1/4 + ... +1/2^{n}}$$

$$s_{n+1}=2^{1/2 + 1/4 + ... +1/2^{n+1}}= s_n 2^{1/2^{n+1}
}
$$

From this how can we say $s_{n+1}\ge s_n?$

And how can we prove that this sequence converges to 2?

Comment: Since $s_n\leqslant2$, $s_{n+1}=\sqrt2\sqrt{s_n}\geqslant\sqrt{s_n}\sqrt{s_n}=s_n$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you. Can u help me with the convergent part

Comment: It is bounded and increasing, right?!

Comment: I'm confused. Why doesn't $s_2 = s_3=s_4=...= 2 ?$

Comment: @AdamRubinson Because $s_2=\sqrt{2\sqrt2}$.

Comment: Oh, that's not what it says though...

Comment: OP - did you mean $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2 \sqrt{s_n}}$ rather than $\sqrt{2} \sqrt{s_n}$ in the question? If so, please edit accordingly.

Comment: @AdamRubinson no. Its $\sqrt{2}$ times $\sqrt{s_n}$

Comment: Ah ok. I read $s_1 = 2$ but this is not what is says. My bad.

Answer (score -1):

If a series is bounded and monoton increasing it converges. You find the limit by $lim s_n=lim s_{n+1}=s$